# Angular: update $scope doesn't work in setTimeout callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In angular.js, `$scope.greeting = xxx` doesn't work in `window.setTimeout`. It has not any effect:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = 'init';
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('update greeting');
        $scope.greeting = "hello"; // doesn't work here.
    }, 3000);
})
```

Why?

The full comparison is below:

- It works (in ajax): http://jsfiddle.net/victorwoo/eDb2S/129/
- It doesn't work (in `window.setTimeout`): http://jsfiddle.net/victorwoo/3b3s6ukp/2/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`setTimeout` operates outside of the `$digest` cycle - therefore angular doesn't know about the change that you applied to `$scope`.

Instead of `window.setTimeout`, use the built in `$timeout` function

See this (your) updated jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rapsac/bbyxch5c/)

Comment: You can also use $scope.$apply within your setTimeout. But $timeout is definitely better.

Answer (score 4):

I think you must use special service from angular

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.greeting = 'init';
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.greeting = "hello";
    }, 2000);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, (as mentioned in answers) you can use `$timeout` instead of `setTimeout`. But in all cases you can use `$scope.$apply()` to change the $scope that is outside of the $digest cycle.

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    $scope.greeting = "hello";
    $scope.$apply();
}, 3000);
```